# What is diff. between driver.wait() , driver.wait(long arg) , driver.wait(long arg0 , int arg1) in selenium web driver

Tags: methods, selenium-webdriver

In Selenium, what is diff. between driver.wait() , driver.wait(long arg) , driver.wait(long arg0 , int arg1)?

Which one is appropriate when?

[image: Reference Image]

Comment: What language binding are you using? In Java, there is no `wait` method on the `WebDriver`interface.

Comment: I am using JAVA. I am getting wait method.

Comment: You'll need to provide more context, then, along with a more complete code sample. There is no `wait` method in the WebDriver API. The closest thing I can think of is the `until` method of the `WebDriverWait` class, but that's a far cry from what you asked.

Comment: I am trying to attach image with question but not working.

Comment: I am using java web driver. I am using Eclipse to do coding. when i write driver and press .[DOT] it shows me all 3 wait methods which I asked in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `wait()` method you're seeing in your IDE is a method inherited from `java.lang.Object`. The documentation on those methods can be found in the [Java language documentation for the Object class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html). The method and its overloads are used in synchronizing object access between threads. They have nothing to do with WebDriver and having the driver wait for page operations to complete.

If you're trying to pause execution for a specific amount of time before moving to the next statement, you can use the [`java.lang.Thread.sleep()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html). However, this is rarely a good idea with WebDriver. Most of the time, when people want to "pause" WebDriver code execution, it's to wait for an operation on the page to be complete, and a hard-coded sleep might wait excessively if the condition is met before the sleep time is complete. For a more efficient wait construct, you'll want to use an instance of the [`WebDriverWait` class](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html), or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for reply. so which method I should use if I want to tell my running driver to stop for 1 minute.?

Comment: That's a separate question, and long back-and-forth Q&A threads in comments are discouraged on StackOverflow. Nevertheless, the answer is [java.lang.Thread.sleep()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html). I hasten to point out that pausing for a hard-coded length of time is rarely a good idea when using WebDriver, because the end goal of what you're trying to accomplish usually can be done more efficiently using other constructs.

Comment: Its better to go for `WebDriverWait` class, still you can use `pause()` method declared in `Actions` class to pause your execution for desired time, but any how pause is deprecated cause of bad design practice.